# How to use Vue on a site with multiple pages?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I have a project in Laravel where I import my app.js is:

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {},
  methods: {},
});
```

This file is imported in my main layout (app.blade.php) like so:

```
  <div id="app">
    @yield('content')
  </div>

  <script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>
  @yield('scripts')
```

I guess you can't instantiate a new Vue instance within another one... so I MUST work with a single Vue instance. The #app div encompasses all of the dynamic content of my multiple-page application, and so my question is... on different pages, how do I separate my Vue.js code? If I put all of the code in app.js, it will get cluttered, and my code will have missing references depending on which page the user is on.

I tried writing a separate `<script></script>` for each page, but this requires me to input the CSRF token for each page, but this feels DRYish.

How do people do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your route should be like this to accept vue router

```
Route::get('/{view?}', function () {
    return view('vue');
})->where('view', '^(?!api\/)[\/\w\.-]*');
```

this will accept every route exept api routes